# Gson fails to "understand" generic type when deserializing

Tags: java, generics, deserialization, gson

I created this memory class:

```
public class Memory {
    private final Hashtable<String, String> data;
    private final Gson gson;

    public Memory() {
        this.data = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    public <T> void set(String key, List<T> value) {
        this.data.put(key, this.gson.toJson(value));
    }

    public <T> List<T> get(String key, Class<T> cls) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();
        return this.gson.fromJson(this.data.get(key), type);
    }
}
```

Where I can store lists of generic types in a json and then deserialize them.
But when I try to use it, for example like this:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;

    public User() { }

    public User(int id, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
    }
}

Memory memory = new Memory();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
// add users
memory.set("users", users);

// now get the users back
List<User> copy = memory.get("users", User.class);
```

Gson returns an ArrayList of StringMap instead of Users.
This obviously has something to do with the generics I'm using, but is there a way to bypass it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real failure here is highlighted by the obvious inconsistency that Java Generics allow, where a `List<User>` ends up being filled with instances of `com.google.gson.internal.StringMap`! But that's a whole other topic.

The immediate problem is that you aren't properly using the type token class. The very point of the token is that you must extend the class with a concrete type - however you are instantiating the class with a method level generic parameter that is validated at compile time then ***erased*** (and subsequently unavailable at runtime). But the whole point of type tokens is to ***retain*** generic information, so the model is blown.

To be honest, this is a failure in implementation of the token - if you compared the constructor code with, for example, the [`TypeReference` implementation of Jackson](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.2/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.java#TypeReference), you would see that Jackson actually validates that concrete parameters are available.

```
31    protected TypeReference()
32    {
33        Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
34        if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
35            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
36        }
45    }
```

The easiest solution would be to simply make constructing the type (token) the responsibility of the caller, and pass it in along with the data you wish to store and/or retrieve.

```
public <T> List<T> get(String key, Type type) {
    return this.gson.fromJson(this.data.get(key), type);
}

public <T> void set(String key, List<T> value, Type type) {
    this.data.put(key, this.gson.toJson(value, type));
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing it, but your suggested solution, while it is easy to implement, kind of misses the point, since I want the whole serialization/deserialization to stay abstract to the user of this `Memory` class. However, now that I understand the limitation, other solutions will probably be more complex.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately there is no easy way around these problems that crop up due to type erasure. If it helps in your design review, requiring a type in library calls is a fairly widespread practice when dealing with genericized collections.